# How to ask curtin to use GPT instead of MBR with MAAS?

Tags: partitioning, maas, gpt

I'm deploying AMD64 nodes with a 3TB first disk with MAAS but I only get a 2TB partition because curtin uses MBR instead of GPT for the partitioning.

Answer (score 2):

Curtin tries to choose the most appropriate partition table type for a given node:

- For systems that are booting in BIOS mode, it defaults to an [MBR-stored DOS partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)
- For systems that are booting in UEFI mode (including ARMv8-based UEFI-enabled systems like Cavium Thunder and APM X-Gene) it defaults to a [GPT partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)

Therefore, the easiest way to get a GPT partition table is to configure the node to boot in UEFI mode, which is supported [starting with MAAS 1.5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1227749).

There are two additional ways to get curtin to create GPT partitions:

- You can modify the curtin configuration provided by MAAS to curtin in `/etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata` to include:

  ```
  block-meta:
      format: gpt
  ```
- If you have up to 4 partitions, you can easily convert DOS partition tables to GPT partitions post-installation. Curtin makes an effort to leave enough space in the partitioning to allow the conversion to successfully happen, and from [r224 onwards it ensures it](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~curtin-dev/curtin/trunk/revision/224). Converting can be done with:

  ```
  sgdisk --mbrtogpt <device>
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, on MAAS 2.0 at least, if you convert an MBR partition on a boot disk to GPT using sgdisk, the system appears to be rendered unbootable.

Comment: See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1616232

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a number of workarounds (including the one suggested in kiko's solution) to no avail.

The following works pretty reliably, at least with MAAS 2.3.5 running on Xenial:

1. Commission the node and partition its disk as you would normally (eg: using the web UI) but stop before deploying the node.
2. Run the following cmd-line query: `maas $USER block-devices read $nodeid` (`$nodeid` can be read from the URL on the web UI for example; it's an internal six alphanum identifier for the node)
3. Grab the block device `id`.  You'll see that `partition_table_type` doggedly says `"MBR"`
4. Now sign-on to MAAS' Postgres DB: `sudo -u postgres psql -d maasdb`
5. Update the partitioning scheme to GPT, `update maasserver_partitiontable set table_type='GPT' where block_device_id=$block_dev_id` (substitute `$block_dev_id with the id you read at step 3)
6. Optionally repeat the query from step 2 and check that the `partition_table_type` has been updated to `GPT`.
7. Deploy the node and enjoy your GPT partition table.

This isn't particularly pretty as hacking directly in MAAS' DB feels a bit off-limits but it's the next best thing until we get given a way to do this through a public API.  The kind of API I have in mind would be smth like: `maas $USER block-device update $node_id $block_device_id partition_table_type=GPT`.  This API already exists and allows updating the `name` of the block device [as documented](https://docs.maas.io/2.3/en/installconfig-block#update-block-device), but ignores the much more useful `partition_table_type` attribute.

Note: if you need to leave unpartitioned space on the GPT target disk, beware that this procedure appears to trigger a "feature" whereby that space gets absorbed by the last partition you lay out in MAAS.  A workaround is to create a throw-away partition and delete it after deployment.